# Python threading, как правильно создать шаред массив?

Tags: python, массивы, многопоточность

У меня демон работает в Х потоков. Им нужен общий массив, в который каждый заносит данные и каждый их читает.

Писать какую-то обмотку вокруг обращения к массиву с семафором внутри - нецелесообразно.

Например, есть переменные специально для потоков. Которые можно без всяких локов доставать и менять из тысячи потоков сразу. Их лишь надо объявить правильно:

```
num = Value('i', 0)
```

Есть ли такое для такого массива, который может менять длину, менять все свои значения, и ни какой из потоков в этот момент с ним работающий не закричит, что массив изменил свою длину?

Answer (score 2):

По определению данные являются общими когда мы с потоками работаем (в этом смысле ничего создавать не надо). В этом их ключевое отличие от процессов, которые имеют изолированную память по умолчанию.

Поэтому проблема в том как *ограничить доступ* к этим общим данным, чтобы потоки не спотыкались друг об друга, иначе говоря -- это проблема синхронизации данных.

> Например, есть переменные специально для потоков. Которые можно без всяких локов доставать и менять из тысячи потоков сразу. Их лишь надо объявить правильно:
>
> ```
> num = Value('i', 0)
> ```

Это неверно. [`multiprocessing.Value()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) работает (с несколькими процессами), потому что этот объект использует `multiprocessing.RLock` внутри.

*"тысячи потоков"* -- само по себе может указывать на проблему ([за редким исключением](http://www.mailinator.com/tymaPaulMultithreaded.pdf)).

> Есть ли такое для такого массива, который может менять длину, менять все свои значения, и ни какой из потоков в этот момент с ним работающий не закричит, что массив изменил свою длину?

Менять длину массива, с которым работают *тысячи потоков сразу* -- это плохая идея: это будет работать *медленно* (из-за постоянной блокировки), в остальных случаях или всё сломается или неверный результат получится. GIL не спасёт, если операции не атомарны на уровне Питона или если GIL умышленно освобождается (`lxml`, `regex`, `numpy`).

Предпочтительные решения:

1. Каждый поток работает на своим участком массива и не лезет на чужие индексы
2. Если общие индексы нужно редактировать достаточно редко, то можно и явную блокировку использовать. Вот [пример кода для нескольких процессов и `numpy` массива (для потоков принцип здесь тот же)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754423/4279). Во многих случаях lock объекты скрыты за более высокоуровневыми интерфейсам.

3. Не использовать массив, а передавать необходимые данные явно, например, через соответствующие методы [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) или самостоятельно с помощью очереди [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) или любой другой удобный для задачи способ обмена сообщениями

В любом случае следует избегать создания своих параллельных структур данных или алгоритмов на основе примитивов многозадачности (таких как семафоры), которые хороши для изобретения увлекательных головоломок, а использовать вместо этого [простые устоявшиеся решения (такие как thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23284285/4279)), если они подходят для конкретного случая. Стоит также рассмотреть есть ли возможность переместить проблему синхронизации в другое уже существующее приложение, например, базу данных (такую как MongoDB).

Comment: "Менять длину массива, с которым работают тысячи потоков сразу -- это плохая идея" - каждый поток, хорошо, их не тысяча, а всего 10, каждый - имеет свой набор значений, минимумов и максимумов для одного объекта. И каждому нужно знать минимум и максимум для всех объектов. Т.е. такой массив должен быть доступен на запись и на чтение всем потокам одновременно, плюс объекты могут возникать у отдельно взятого потока, и пропадать, т.е. длина переменная.

Comment: @anonymous: если каждому потоку необходимо знать всё о всех, то это ещё хуже. Это похоже на [XY вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044). В чём конечная цель -- улучшить производительность? Если у Вас есть рабочее (возможно медленное) однопоточное решение, то Вы может задать отдельный вопрос о том как его можно распараллелить (или улучшить производительность другим путём). Желательно минимальный, но полный пример кода использовать, а также добавить словесное описание, что о кода ожидается.

Comment: да, это XY. Десять разных потоков - шаряца по десяти разным сайтам. У каждого потока соответственно свои данные обо всём, но всем им надо знать данные обо всех остальных. В один поток такое не нарисуешь.

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной python библиотеке `multiprocessing` есть набор [типов](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes). Возможно вам один из них подойдёт. Или посмотрите на [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). В принципе тоже массив.